# Oracle sql worksheet

Tags: sql, oracle, worksheet, ora-00913

I'm trying to compare 2 columns and the goal is the return of the lines that don't match. For example I have in column 1 and 2 the following

```
1                     2
id name age job       id  name  age  job
1   aaa  11 bbb        1   aaa   11   bbb
2   ccc  22 ddd        2   ccc   22   eee
```

the return I'm looking for is

```
2  ccc 22  ddd
2  ccc 22  eee
```

I'm trying to use the following

```
select id, name, age from 1 where id in
(
select id, name, age from 1
minus
select id, name, age from 2
)
union all
select id, name, age from 2 where id in
(
select id, name, age from 1
minus
select id, name, age from 2
)
order by id
```

I get the following error

```
ORA-00913: demasiados valores
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 1
```

That refers to the line with the 1st `(`

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The specific error you are getting is because of the following:

```
where id in ( select id, name, age from
```

You can not use an in clause to compare a single value of ID to 3 other values.

```
-- get values in 1 not in 2
SELECT 1.id, 1.name, 1.age 
FROM 1
LEFT JOIN 2 on 1.id = 2.id and 1.name = 2.name and 1.age = 2.age
WHERE 2.id is null
UNION
-- get values in 2 not in 1
SELECT 2.id, 2.name, 2.age 
FROM 2
LEFT JOIN 1 on 2.id = 1.id and 2.name = 1.name and 2.age = 1.age
WHERE 1.id is null
```

Comment: Was similar to your post
What i did was

`(
select * from 1 minus select * from 2) 
union all 
(select * from 2 minus select * from 1)`

and worked exacly what i wanted
thx for your time

Comment: I chose the left anti join pattern since it is more portable SQL wise to other systems, but yes a minus in oracle would work as wel